# Would like to make braces larger using Fourier package

Tags: braces, fourier

in my MWE below, I wanted to know if it is possible to make the "{ }" larger like this (while still using the fourier package):

[image]

Here is my code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{fourier}
\usepackage{amsmath,amsfonts,amssymb,amsthm,bm}
\usepackage{arydshln}
\usepackage{physics}

\begin{document}

\begin{equation}
1 \leq \mathbf{E}\{\tilde{\theta}^{2}(k)\}\mathbf{E}\Bigg\{\left[\pdv{}{\theta}\ln p(\mathbf{Z})\right]^{2}\Bigg\}
\end{equation}

\end{document}
```

Comment: same as always `\left\{...\right\}` should make automatically stretching or `\bigl\{..\bigr\}`  or `\Bigl\{`  etc fixed size brackets

Comment: Use `\left` and `\right` instead of `\Bigg`; note also that you should use `\bigl` and `\bigr` (and similarly for the other sizes), not just `\big \Big \bigg \Bigg`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I assume you want to enlarge both pairs of curly braces. I suggest you try `\bigl\{ ... \bigr\}` for the first pair, and `\left\{ ... \right\}` for the second pair.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath,fourier,physics}
\DeclareMathOperator{\E}{\mathbf{E}}

\begin{document}
\begin{equation}
1 \leq \E\bigl\{\tilde{\theta}^{2}(k)\bigr\}
       \E\left\{\Biggl[ \pdv{}{\theta}
          \ln p(\mathbf{Z}) \Biggr]^{2}\right\}
\end{equation}
\end{document}
```

Comment: @Micro, Thank you for your solution.  What exactly made the "{ }" behave differently in your solution?

Comment: @Joe - I exchanged the ordering of the sizing instructions -- `\Biggl[` and `\Biggr]` for the inner pair of large fences, and `\left\{` and `\right\}` for the outer pair.